# Android TableLayout with weights on rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

im trying to create a table and add the same space to columns in table. My code is below, but my second collumn doesnt have the same space like first one.
Like you see on image that i posted below too, the first row(header) doesnt have the same space than the body(second row).

Hope someone can help me to undesratnd what is wrong with this

[image: Result is this]

What i want

[image]

And my code is:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.6" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1" />
        </TableRow>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6" >        

                        <TextView
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                       />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want it to be perfectly aligned? Like all rows should be same as the first row?

Comment: Yes. I didnt put an image about what i want,but thats the point. I will add,then

Comment: Not sure why on earth isn't your xml giving you an error as you have not specified layout_width in your widgets. You need to specify the widths of these images to be 0dp not the height.change height to wrap_content

Comment: I need that for scroll view below

Answer (score 5):

Please set `layout_width="0dp"` to items in `<TableRow>` tag, see the following example

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"    <--Here-->
                android:layout_weight="0.6" />
```

Hope to help you